# SQL INNER JOIN with WHERE clause to LINQ format

Tags: sql, linq, inner-join, where-clause

How would I convert this sql query to LINQ?

```
SELECT company.ticker, company.primary_analyst, 
       personnel.last_name, company.research_associate,
       company.secondary_associate, company.coverage_status
FROM company 
     INNER JOIN personnel ON company.primary_analyst = personnel.dpinitials
WHERE personnel.last_name='marley' AND company.associate='ml'
ORDER BY company.coverage_status
```

Comment: see [Converting SQL to LINQ, Part 6: Joins (Bill Horst)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/12/31/converting-sql-to-linq-part-6-joins-bill-horst.aspx) unfortunately its to VB... well

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty similar:

```
var results = from c in company
              join p in personnel on c.primary_analyst equals p.dpinitals
              where p.last_name == 'marley' and c.associate == 'ml'
              orderby c.coverage_status asc
              select new 
              {
                c.ticker, c.primary_analyst, p.last_name, c.research_associate,  
                c.secondary_associate, c.coverage_status
              };
```

Above projects to an anonymous class with the properties you want - if you have an equivalent POCO class in your model you should project to that, if not in many cases you probably should create one.

Comment: I'm using LINQPad.  Is there a way to do my query as a "C# Expression"?

Answer (score 2):

The solution from @BrokenGlass is perfectly fine.
However, if you have a 1..many relationship it is rarely necessary to use the join operator in LINQ. In this example, if company->personell was 1..many, I would write the query like this:

```
var results = from c in company
              where c.associate == "ml"
              from p in c.personnel
              where p.last_name == "marley"
              orderby c.coverage_status asc
              select new
              {
                  c.ticker, 
                  c.primary_analyst, 
                  p.last_name, 
                  c.research_associate,  
                  c.secondary_associate, 
                  c.coverage_status
              };
```

This can also be written using the expression chain syntax:

```
var results = company.Where(c => c.associate == "ml")
                     .SelectMany(c => c.personnel, (c, p) => new
                     {
                         c.ticker, 
                         c.primary_analyst, 
                         p.last_name,  
                         c.research_associate,  
                         c.secondary_associate, 
                         c.coverage_status
                     })
                     .Where(x => x.last_name == "marley")
                     .OrderBy(x => x.coverage_status)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   var list = (from u in db.Users
                       join c in db.Customers on u.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
                       where u.Username == username
                       select new {u.UserId, u.CustomerId, u.ClientId, u.RoleId, u.Username, u.Email, u.Password, u.Salt, u.Hint1, u.Hint2, u.Hint3, u.Locked, u.Active,c.ProfilePic}).First();
```

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation? That would reduce the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.